# What's wrong with my spider?

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

[image] I want to crawl to all the web pages using crawl spider and rule I implement but unable to get the data extracted through the rule don't know why?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from urlparse import urljoin
from delhivery.items import DelhiveryItem




class criticspider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "delh"
    allowed_domains = ["consumercomplaints.in"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.consumercomplaints.in/?search=delhivery&page=1"]

    rules = (
        # Extracting pages, allowing only links with page=number to be extracted 
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="pagelinks"]', ), allow=('page=\d+', )),follow=True, callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = DelhiveryItem()
        sites = response.xpath('//table[@width="100%"]')
        items=[]
        for site in sites:
            item['title'] = response.xpath('.//td[@class="complaint"]/a/span/text()').extract()[0]
            # item['subtitle'] = response.xpath('<write xpath>').extract()[0]
            # item['date'] = response.xpath('<write xpath>').extract()[0].strip()
            # item['username'] = response.xpath('<write xpath>').extract()[0]
            #item['link'] = response.url
            # item['data'] = response.xpath('<write xpath>').extract()[0]
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Comment: Can you share your log output ?

Comment: check the image of my output screen

Comment: It is not clear readable but it seems you are facing a lot of redirects. Check the exact code you are looking for and compare with the code of analyzed pages to find if it match